# Unable to connect to git repo via application

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, simple-git

I have a node app. Trying to connect to a git repo via the app.

It works locally. It also works when I docker build and run it via container locally.

But when I deploy it, getting the following error.

> Error: Cloning into '/opt/app-root/dist/temp_repo'... fatal: unable to
> access 'https://github.companyDomain.com/owner/repo-name.git/':
> CONNECT tunnel failed, response 404
>
> CONNECT - HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "-"
> "git/2.38.5" "583aa8-0b75-47a5-a90e-3f0bc2aab696"
> "github.companyDomain.com:443

Why?

My code in the main index.js file.

```
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';

const url = `https://validUserName:validPATToken@github.companyDomain.com/owner/repo-name.git`;

export const clone = async () => {
  await simpleGit().clone(url, '/opt/app-root/dist/temp_repo', {
    '--branch': 'main',
    '--single-branch': null,
    '--depth': '1',
  });
};

await clone();
```

P.S: When deployed, I have set firewall rules for github.companyDomain.com TLS 443 and HTTPS 80.

Deployment is to a company owned internal server which I don't fully control.

Is not like AWS or Azure. Is self managed Kubernetes based if this info matters.

Comment: Kubernetes with Istio? `404 NR route_not_found` looks like Istio complaining that it either cannot find a route or that it cannot find a matching filter chain for a downstream connection.

Comment: @JimRedmond Yes with Istio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Kubernetes cluster is utilizing Istio, and the error message `404 NR route_not_found` means Istio is unable to find a route or a matching filter chain for the downstream connection when your application is attempting to clone the git repository. The `404 NR` error code stands for "No Route" and indicates that a routing problem exists within the Istio configuration. Here's how you might address or investigate this issue further:

Make sure there is a [`VirtualService`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) and [`DestinationRule`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/) configuration for `github.companyDomain.com` or ensure that the external traffic to `github.companyDomain.com` is properly handled in your Istio configuration.
If there is a `VirtualService` configuration for `github.companyDomain.com`, make sure the routes are correctly defined and that they point to the correct `DestinationRule` and subsets, if applicable.

Create a [`ServiceEntry`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) to allow traffic to `github.companyDomain.com`. A `ServiceEntry` informs Istio how to handle external traffic.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
    name: github-external
spec:
    hosts:
    - github.companyDomain.com
    ports:
    - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
    resolution: DNS
    location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

---

See also [this discussion](https://discuss.istio.io/t/virtualservice-configuration-help/3965) which involves adding a match section for the path in question to the first `VirtualService` so that it routes to the correct service. Similarly, in your case, check the routing configurations in your Istio setup correctly match the paths and hosts your application is trying to access might help resolve the 404 NR route_not_found error.